# Aggregate chapter notebooks into a book

Tags: document-creation

I would like to build a book from chapter notebooks.  I prefer to do this in a separate notebook that does something like the following: reads in a list of chapter notebooks (I'll provide the list explicitly), evaluates each chapter notebook (perhaps all together), numbers the chapters and sections appropriately (i.e., sequentially), creates a properly paginated table of contents (e.g., using `MakeContents`), and produces the final PDF.  This seems like a very basic need, but I'm not finding the guidance I need.  As an aside, there are a few operations I would like to do on the book as a whole (say, after assembling it into a single notebook) rather than chapter by chapter.  Needless to say, I want the underlying chapter notebooks left untouched by this process.  Clues?

Comment: Please show us how far have you gone with your own attempts coding this.

Comment: Not far at all: I'm seeking guidance even as to approach.  For example, do people who do this kind of thing really rely on the Wolfram author tools?  The interface description is so high level that I'm not sure it is appropriate to my project.  It seems to emphasize GUI interaction with the project, which is not what I want.  However it provides `MakeContents` which seems potentially very useful, despite being unclear about how the contents itself will be numbered.  Furthermore, iiuc, the underlying notebooks are changed ...

Comment: Unless someone done something very similar and decides to post is soon I'm afraid this question will be closed as unlear/too broad. But maybe you can provide some minial example of e.g 2 notebooks with 4 cells each with minimal content and the expected result description.